# Drawn objects not drawing in correct position

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a paint program except I have a major problem, I want to draw a square where I click the mouse, except the shape is not drawing in the right place, here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Paint_Program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int mousex;
        int mousey;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



        }

        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mousex = Cursor.Position.X;
            mousey = Cursor.Position.Y;
            System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
            formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(mousex, mousey, 20, 20));
            myBrush.Dispose();
            formGraphics.Dispose();


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void rectangleShape1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //testing 
            Console.WriteLine("X:" + mousex);
            Console.WriteLine("Y: " + mousey);
        }
    }
}
```

I would really like to know how to solve this problem, and I would be really happy if some one could help me :D

Comment: There should be many questions on converting mouse position between different windows - figure out what mouse position is relative too and adjust appropriately.

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics.  It's a temp drawing that will get erased on the minimization of the form or by another form covering it.  Use the paint event of the drawing control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using the `Coursor.Position` property which provides cursor position in the screen coordinates:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx

What you are interested in are coordinates of the cursor relative to your window. In your event handler you can access it easily using the `MouseEventArgs e` method parameter like that `new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 20, 20)`

Below modified version of the `Form1_MouseClick` event handler that I assume works as you expected:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mousex = Cursor.Position.X;
        mousey = Cursor.Position.Y;
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
        formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 20, 20));
        myBrush.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand where do I put: new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 20, 20)?

Comment: It's in the Form1_MouseClick method. You can see it in the method body I provided. It replaced the previous version where you were using mousex and mousey variables: new Rectangle(mousex, mousey, 20, 20).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are 2 sets of coordinates, one is coordinates for the whole screen and the other one is coordinates for the control where you try to draw. you need to convert between those two sets of coordinates. Take a look at the PointToScreen method in the COntrol class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

the position is in relation of you primary screen, (0,0) is the top left of your primary screen, what you want is the mouse position of the control you are drawing on:

for example:
Panel1.MousePosition;